# JSF chars get double UTF-8 encoded

Tags: java, jsf, character-encoding

last week I asked a question but JSF and charset encoding

[relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006826/jsf-form-and-german-umlauts)

Now I included this JSF in my JBoss Portal env. with the common jboss portlet bridge. When I submit my form something weird happens:

The portal is UTF-8 so my form inputs are UTF-8 too but after the submit the chars are encoded as UTF-8 again which causes something like this

```
Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼
```

If the response page is submitted again it turns into this

```
ÃÂ¤ÃÂ¶ÃÂ¼
```

You can hit the submit button and see the chars getting encoded everytime again.

Is this working as intended?

Comment: did any answer on the other question work for you? and which one?

Comment: as for this question - I think you should read the docs about how the portlet bridge handles encoding

Comment: regarding the docs - to be more specific - source code, the bridge inherits the encoding of the portal. And this is UTF-8.

Answer (score 6):

This will happen when the data which is initially decoded using `UTF-8` has been incorrectly encoded using `ISO-8859-1`. You can easily reproduce this by:

```
String input1 = new String("äöü");
System.out.println(input1); // äöü
String input2 = new String(input1.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(input2); // Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼
String input3 = new String(input2.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(input3); // ÃÂ¤ÃÂ¶ÃÂ¼
```

(note that the last one actually contains more characters, but SO's message parser ate them).

This means that somewhere in your webapp `ISO-8859-1` was incorrectly been used instead of `UTF-8`. It's hard to pinpoint the root cause with the as far given information. You can try to sysout the request parameters in the JSF bean action method and read the output in stdout (you only need to ensure that the stdout is using `UTF-8` as well! if you're using an IDE like Eclispe, you can configure that in [Workspace preferences](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#DevelopmentEnvironment)). If those chars looks garbage as well, then it's the request encoding which is wrong. If those chars looks fine, then it's the response or webbrowser encoding which is wrong. To exclude the webbrowser from being suspect, then you can in e.g. Firefox determine the encoding used by *View* > *Character Encoding*.

Comment: I've changed my logging to debug and enabled my jboss to log every request. It seems that the chars are corrupt after my submit, the log shows the unicode chars only as ????.

I'm using a JBoss 4.2.3 Server atm.

Comment: The logger needs to be configured to use `UTF-8`. This is not per-se the root cause of this particular problem however. Reread the article to **understand** the bits about character encoding.